# WatchKit - SwiftUI - List index scroll

Tags: swiftui, watchkit, apple-watch

I am building an Apple Watch app in SwiftUI.
I am trying to build a contact list (which I succeeded) but am unsuccessful in implementing scrolling like in the phone app where you can scroll quickly between letters.
Like so:
[image: Apple Watch contacts]

This is my code:

```
struct ContactSelectionView: View, FlowableElement {
var id: String = "ContactSelectionView"
@ObservedObject var viewModel: ContactSelectionViewModel

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if viewModel.contactsSections.count > 0 {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.contactsSections) { data in
                    Section(header: Text(data.letter)) {
                        ForEach(data.items) { contact in
                            viewModel.nextButton(id: id, data: FlowData.contact(contact.name)) {
                                Text(contact.name)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(EllipticalListStyle())
        } else {
            Text("Loading contacts...")
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Contact Selection")
}}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - How to add "letters sections" and alphabet jumper in a Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65185161/swiftui-how-to-add-letters-sections-and-alphabet-jumper-in-a-form)

Comment: No, that code creates a bar on the side of the vc that you can use to tap and scroll to a specific letter. It doesn't give the me what I am looking for

Comment: The logic is simple with ScrollViewReader but that view next to the Digital Crown is the part that I don’t think is available publicly.

Answer (score -1):

Use scrollto(), add a number to each contact added, then have it add 1 or subtract one depending on the direction of the scroll wheel. I suggest putting these in an array of some kind. that way you can run something that adds the name and number to the array every time a contact is added.

Comment: thank you for takin the time to answer the question. your answer doesn't really address any of the Apple Watch specific UI concerns :(